# Deformations of Kähler manifolds are Kähler.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Suppose $f: X \to B$ is a proper and smooth morphism of complex manifolds, and suppose the fiber $X_0 \subset X$ over $0 \in B$ is a Kähler manifold. How can I show that there is a neighbourhood $U \subset B$ of $0$, such that all fibers $X_t, t \in U$ are also Kähler manifolds?

Here is my attempt:

Let $h = g - i \omega$ be the Hermitian metric on $X$ with Riemannian metric $g = \Re(h)$ and $- \omega = \Im(h)$, such that $\omega_0 = \omega|_{X_0}$ is a Kähler form. I think such a metric can be choosen using a partition of unity on an open cover, which trivializes both the tangent bundle of $X$ and the tangent bundle of $X_0$.

But now I don't know why $\omega_t = \omega|_{X_t}$ would still be closed, for $t \in B$ nearby $0$. If I choose a differential geometric trivialization $f^{-1}(U) \cong X_0 \times U$ (by Ehresmann's theorem), then I can consider $d\omega_t$ as a (continuous?) function $U \to H^3_{\text{dR}}(X_0, \mathbb R)$. However, the zero-set of a continuous function is closed, not open...

I stumbled upon this when reading a proposition by Beauville[1], that claims that if $X_0$ is Kähler and holomorphically symplectic, then the neighbouring fibers are as well Kähler and holomorphically symplectic. The Kähler part is not elaborated on though.

[1] Proposition 9 in *Varietés Kähleriennes dont la première Classe de Chern est nulle*.

Comment: I can't recall, but isn't there some continuous (on $B$) invariant which is only positive when $X$ is Kahler? Then you just pick a neighborhood in $B$ in which that invariant has no zeroes.

Comment: This is a Theorem of Kodaira, see [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969879?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents), section 6.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ehresman’s theorem you can assume $X=B \times X_0$ where $X_0$ is compact Kähler – the complex structure on $X_0$ varies with the basis point though (ie the isomorphism $X_t \subset X \rightarrow X_0$ ($t \in B$) is real-smooth, not holomorphic).

Let $\omega_0$ be a Kähler form on $X_0$, $\omega$ its pullback to $X$. Then $\omega$ is a closed $2$-form on $X$, thus so are its restrictions to each $X_t$. And now consider the projection of $\omega_t$ on the subspace of $(1,1)$-forms for $X_t$: it’s still closed and it is a Kähler form.

Comment: You cannot pull-back from $X_0$ to $X$, so how to conclude that $\omega$ is closed? In general this will not be true: Consider a non-Kähler manifold $X$ and take $f=\operatorname{id}_X$.

Comment: Ehresmann says I can (provided the map is a submersion on a neighborhood of $X_0$), since $X \rightarrow B$ is *smoothly* (not holomorphically) diffeomorphic to $X_0 \times B \rightarrow B$, up to shrinking the basis.

Comment: Yes, I know the Ehresmann theorem. I don't understand how you want to pull-back $\omega_0$ from $X_0$ to $X$. By the projection map $X_0 \times B \to X_0$?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant. Pull-back of differential forms maps a closed form to a closed form (since it commutes with the differential).

Comment: Sorry for coming back to this only now, but I didn't bother to check the details of your construction before. So I see that the form you produce is a real, $(1,1)$-form on $X_t$. But I don't see why it is closed, non-degenerate or [compatible with the complex structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_manifold#Symplectic_viewpoint) of $X_t$. For the closedness, if $\omega_t = \omega^{20}+\omega^{11}+\omega^{02}$, then $0 = d\omega_t = d\omega^{20} + d\omega^{11} + d\omega^{02}$, but it is not clear to me why the individual summands should vanish.

Comment: Wow, that was a *long* time ago… non-degeneracy is an open condition, so we can just shrink $B$. But closedness is actually a problem (I guess I was sure that the $(1,1)$ projection of a closed form was closed, not sure what I was thinking). “Compatibility with complex structure” looks like a problem too (the form taken at $(u,J_tv)$ will be symmetric because that’s the definition of $(1,1)$ iirc, but positive definiteness is definitely not open)… I need to think about fixes, because as is, my answer clearly will not work.

Comment: I think I have a fix, but it looks much too good, so could you please check it? Let $F \subset \Omega^2$ be the subsheaf of real closed $(1,1)$-forms $u$ on $X$ such that we always have $u(x,Jy)=u(y,Jx)$. $F$ is still a sheaf on $X$, and $\omega_0 \in H^0(X_0,F)$ where $X_0 \subset X$ is compact. Thus (sheaf magic [I think]) $\omega_0$ comes from a section $\omega \in F(U)$. Up to reducing $U$, we can assume that $\omega_x(u,Jv)$ is always positive definite on the kernel of $T_y X \rightarrow T_{f(y)} B$. By properness $U$ contains $f^{-1}(t)$ for $t \in B$ close to $0$ so we’re done.